# How can I store users-preferences in Azure-AD?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, storage, preferences

I created an ASP MVC application and I want to use Azure-AD to retrieve information about users already stored in Azure to define role and preferences. I saw some tutorials to define roles but I don't find anything about storing preferences. For example, I would like to store filter-preferances or language preferances. How is it possible to store the users-preferance when using Azure AD. Is it possible to store it in Azure?

Comment: Will custom data apply to your requirement? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview

Answer (score 1):

you can add custom claims in you azure AD, and there keep all information what you need. Please check this link [azure ad docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims).

Your Application can filter preferences by these custom claims but these you need to code